# How do I go about this? A question about Canadian TRV for business

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens

I want to know this.

I applied for Canadian TRV for Tourist purposes. I want to visit some VC's for my startup.
Now here is what i want to know, I am making it an "open meeting" as I would be going to meet them one by one after registering the company in the state of Ottawa.
I did not get invites from them, i will be going to meet them in person. As many a time, they do not seem to give conscession to businesses outside canada.

I dont have an invitation from the VC's, instead i included all the activities in my itenerary. Please advice if this is a good approach.

Comment: Related: [Immigration Options for Starting a Business in Canada as a Foreigner](https://sobirovs.com/startups/start-a-business-in-canada/).

Comment: How far along the process of setting up this business are you?  If you’re in the (very) early stages, why do you need to be physically present in Canada? Meetings with potential investors can be done virtually.